# IntelliJ IDEA and Maven in Windows

Tags: windows, maven, plugins, intellij-idea

There is a project that definitely uses Maven.
In IntelliJ IDEA in Windows, when the project is opened, there are such errors in the Maven Projects area as

```
Unresolved plugin: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1
Unresolved plugin: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1
```

and many other similar unresolved plugins.
Also, all of Maven projects in the Maven Projects area are underlined with red.

So, something definitely needs to be done with Maven. However, I'm not sure what exactly.

As http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven.html#d661509e173 says, IntelliJ IDEA fully integrates with Maven version 2.2 and later versions. However, I'm not sure:

1. if it comes with IntelliJ IDEA program, or
2. I have to install the Maven plugin in IDEA, or
3. I have to follow Installation instructions for Windows from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation

P.S. Java is installed, `java -version` says it is `1.7.0_60`

Comment: have you executed "mvn install" once? or "mvn dependency:go-offline" so all dependencies and plugins are downloaded? If the artifacts have not yet been resolved from a maven repo intellij sometimes marks them as missing (since they are not locally available). the goals should fix that

Comment: > have you executed "mvn install" once? or "mvn dependency:go-offline" - neither of both. Should I do it in the cmd? It says mvn is not recognized.

Comment: you can do that within intellij if you havent setup maven for command line usage yet (which I would recommend :) ). Go to the Menu "Run", choose "Run..." and add a new Maven build. Choose the parent pom and the goals and your good to go